# how to retrieve the values that contains a part of value in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

Suppose I have a column lastName and I have the data as

```
kumar yadav
kumar shah
raghu.
kumar
```

Now I want to write a SQL query that to get the values whose last name contains kumar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `like` operator

```
select *
from tablename
where lastname like '%kumar%'
```