# How to retrieve the data from the column that contains kumar

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, uitableview

Suppose in a table I have a column as First_Name and Last_Name, the value in the Last_Name column are : kumar,kumar yadav, kumar, kumar jha. Now I want to write the SQL query to retrieve all the last_Name that has kumar in it.

Comment: Well, you have 3 answers that are basically the exact same thing.

Comment: How is this question different to your last question which already has an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to retrieve the values that contains a part of value in the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55862588/how-to-retrieve-the-values-that-contains-a-part-of-value-in-the-column)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1
where last_name like '%kumar%'
```

This query return all data with the word kumar into to all the value.

Comment: As from the above query, it is not going to return the value from the row that has Kumar yadav.  It returns only the column that has only kumar. I want all the column that has kumar. For example if a column has kumar yadav then it should also come in the result.

Comment: So basically, you need `WHERE [Field1] LIKE '%kumar%' OR [Field2] LIKE '%kumar%'` and so on...

Comment: @Pankaj4U  but this query with like sentence with '%%' return all the rows with the value you put it , if you wanna only start with kumar so try this : last_name like 'kumar%' .

Comment: Do you have case sensitivity turned on in your SQL Server? It's off by default I thought so this query would return both upper and lower matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from [yourtable]
where last_Name like '%kumar%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table_Name
where lower(last_Name) like lower('%kumar%')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select *
from Table
where PATINDEX (last_name,'^(.)*(kumar)+(.)*$') !=0;
```